# ContentType and metadata give permission denied in storage write rules

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I can't seem to get MetadataChange to work with the storage rules.

I use Unity.

I set the MetadataChange similar to the docs:

```
var newMetadata = new MetadataChange
        {
            CustomMetadata = new Dictionary<string, string> 
            {        
                {"check", "1"}      
            },

            ContentType = "image/jpg"
        };

        await imageRef.PutBytesAsync(bytes, newMetadata).ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) => {
```

Then when I try:

```
allow write: if request.resource.contentType.matches('image/jpg');
```

Or

```
allow write: if request.resource.metadata['check'] == '1';
```

Neither of these work. I get permission denied error.

I was able to get many other rules working, but never these two.

```
read: resource.contentType.matches('image/jpg')
```

Seems to be working fine.

Thank you.